# Java, how to merge smaller classes via 1 big class?

Tags: java, class

Imagine having the following classes:

```
Head
Torso
Hands
Legs
```

that I would like to keep but link them via a new class `Human`. This is what their codes look like:

```
package myEntities;

public class Head {

    private float headSize;

    Head(float headSize) {
        this.headSize = headSize;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { }

    public float[] getHeadSize() {
        return headSize;
    }
}
```

repeated the same for the other 3 parts except for the name. If I wanted to make a human class, how would it look like? I'm thinking something like this but this seems too repetitive:

```
package myEntities;

public class Human {

    private Head headObject = new Head(variable1);
    private Torso torsoObject = new Torso(variable2);
    private Leg rightLegObject = new Leg(variable3);


    Human(float variable1, float variable2, float variable3) {

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) { }
```

And this way gives an error of not being able to resolve `variable1` and the rest of the variables.

Comment: Where have you declared `variable1`, `variable2` and `variable3`?

Comment: If the values you need for the different body parts are only present in the constructor, you can only create these body parts inside the constructor.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was struggling with that. I thought they didn't need to be declared as they are passed with the class call because if i also declare them then i would have to supply them and supply the values for the Head, Torso and Leg and go on a loop or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your human class, the constructor should be a Human constructor (not a Zombie - Zombie could be a superclass, a subclass, or a completely separate class)

```
public class Human {

    Human(float variable1, float variable2, float variable3) {

    }
}
```

Second, you need to declare the object members like you are doing, but initialize them in your constructor

```
Human {
    private Head headObject;
    private Torso torsoObject; 
    private Leg rightLegObject;

    public Human (float variable1, float variable2, float variable3) {
      headObject = new Head(variable1);
      torsoObject = new Torso(variable2);
      rightLegObject = new Leg(variable3);
   }
}
```

Comment: the zombie was a typo i left while copying and pasting, thank you! This works perfectly! This is what i was looking for

Comment: @Doesitmatter great. Please click the check next to the solution to mark your question answered

Comment: I can't for another 6 mins but i promise you i will ;)